# Data prefetching using scheduled tasks in an ASP.NET environment

Tags: asp.net, .net, scheduling, filesystemwatcher, quartz.net

We're developing an ASP.Net application that retrieve data from WCF services.

The user interface (develped with JQM and ASP.NET) shows a loading panel while the request is processed and data are server-side paged so our db returns only first n records per request.

In this scenario, user performs a search and until he navigates through pages, we want to prefetch results of the next n pages to store in a RAM cache object to avoid delay.

To do this we've created a scheduled process with quartz.net, triggered every 3 seconds, that checks a FIFO queue to request data for subsequent pages.
Scheduled JOB is configured to allow quartz.net to execute concurrent execution and quartz.net is set to use a maximum of 10 threads.

In your opinion, is this a good approach?

Which may be the issues?

Can the intensive use of a job (fired every 3 second) and eventually threads cause the application to be unstable?

A solution based on a FileSystemWatcher trigger would be better?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you cannot avoid the delay when the user searches for the first time. In such a case you can make an ajax request to cache data for subsequent requests.

If you are using classic asp.net then this link discusses making ajax calls in asp.net http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/11/07/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods-by-example.aspx

If you are decide to use quartz, then you need to embed it in asp.net application, which is an overhead.

Comment: we've considered this option but is not good because if user go to another site page what happen to the ajax request? With server side scheduling, it's possible to change page and if user returns and makes the same search, data are still cached.

Comment: @hyppos can you edit your question with possible work flows starting with search page and how you are using quartz, this might help in getting better overview of your scenario ?